# How to overwrite an excel using excelize of golang

Tags: excel, go, excelize

I want to overwrite some data on a designed excel already with golang.
So I found a module named excelize.
I tried to read and write seeing the document as below.

```
func main() 

    f, err := excelize.OpenFile("ab.xlsx")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    rows, err := f.GetRows("Sheet1")
    for _, row := range rows {
        for _, colCell := range row {
            fmt.Print(colCell, "\t")
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

I can read data or write excel.
But my goal is I just want to read an excel with cell designed and overwrite just data on it.
How can I make this? Can you give me some advice? 
Thank you for reading it.

Answer (score 2):

```
f, err := excelize.OpenFile("ab.xlsx")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

if err := f.SaveAs("Book2.xlsx"); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

I found the solution. Thank you.

Comment: It also works with the same file by using f.Save(). But this will not work if the file is manually opened already. It would fail saying the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. Close the file and use Save() or keep the file open and use SaveAs("other.xlsx")